# Ionic 3 native email composer show error "plugin_not_installed"

Tags: typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am using [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/) in ionic 3 app. The plugin is installed. And `cordova-plugin-email-composer` folder is available in `plugins` folder. I have also uninstalled and reinstall it meany times. But it shows an error "plugin_not_installed".

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="^0.8.10" />
```

**TypeScript**

```
   this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) =>{
      if(available) {
        let email = {
            to: 'example@example.com',
            subject: "User Feedback",
            body: "",
            isHtml: true
          };
          this.emailComposer.open(email);

      }else{
        this.presentToast("Your mobile don't have any app for sending emails.")
      }
     }).catch(error=>{
      this.presentToast(JSON.stringify(error));   //this show plugin_not_installed
     });
```

Comment: Do you run this on your emulator/phone or in the browser?

Comment: I am testing it on my phone

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/c11aec33a7570d623ea693700e2d83fce22b4e2d/src/%40ionic-native/core/plugin.ts#L38) is the line where your error comes from. Meaning ionic-native is not able to find the plugin. Try removing `platforms`, `plugins`, `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` (you may also have to remove the refs in `config.xml` and `package.json`) and then run `npm install`, `cordova platform add android`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  //Your code
 });
```

**Old:**

Can you try this and let us know.

```
ionic cordova platform remove android

ionic cordova platform add android
```

Comment: See the **Update**

Comment: I think it will still not work because the code is on a button click event.